# Cannot set header labels in tableview

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

So I want to change the labels of the tableview but keep getting an error when using the code I have found on other questions.

I am using the setHorizontalHeaderLabels code to add them.

```
class Setup(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Setup, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.png'))
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Auto-Annoucement - Setup')
        self.showMaximized()
        self.createTable()
        self.setupmon = QWidget()
        self.setup_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.setupmon)
        self.setup_layout.addWidget(self.tableViewmon)

    def createTable(self):
        self.modelmon = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.modelmon.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self, ['Time', 'File Name'])
        self.tableViewmon = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)
        self.tableViewmon.setModel(self.modelmon)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    setup = Setup()
    setup.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I keep getting the error: 
TypeError: setHorizontalHeader(self, QHeaderView): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Setup'

Comment: `self.modelmon.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Time', 'File Name'])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> void QTableWidget::setHorizontalHeaderLabels(const QStringList &labels)
>
> Sets the horizontal header labels using labels.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Setup(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Setup, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.png'))
        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Auto-Annoucement - Setup')
        self.showMaximized()
        self.createTable()
        self.setupmon = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.setupmon)                                      # +++
        
        self.setup_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.setupmon)
        self.setup_layout.addWidget(self.tableViewmon)
        

    def createTable(self):
        self.modelmon = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        
#        self.modelmon.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self, ['Time', 'File Name'])
        self.modelmon.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Time', 'File Name'])            # +++
        
        self.tableViewmon = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)
        self.tableViewmon.setModel(self.modelmon)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    setup = Setup()
    setup.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]